# Modifying R - RShiny Datatable Filter Behaviour

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, sqldf, dt

I have a few tables (10-15) that are several million rows long. I'd like to expose them via the DT feature in RShiny with the ability to filter in real-time. However, because it can take a long time to filter a table that is sufficiently large, I'd like to use my own function that can be applied on the filters to retrieve the results (rather than having datatable process the same).

1) Using a custom filter function

As a simple example, if the data was coming from a sql table, t as follows:

`a b c
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 2 3`

And if I had to find all values of a == 1, I can either use the DataTable filter or instead send a query back - eg., `select * from t where a==1`. Similarly, `select * from t where a==1, b==2, ...` etc. The latter method (select from ...) is what I'd like to use. I am using an HPC Timeseries database that could process these queries much faster than using the in-built functionality.

2) I'd also like to be able to interact with the page number so that I retrieve only those rows that are required for the current display. Taking the above table, t as an example, if the user was on page 1, I'd only retrieve the first x rows (eg., 10 rows is Show 10 Entries were selected) and when the user clicks on Page 2, I'd retrieve the next set of 10 rows.

There is a slight caveat in that the pagination happens automatically, but I'd be able to provide the count of rows such that the pagination can be accurate (eg., based on the user filter criteria the count of the table is x rows, and hence show x/10 pagination buttons)

I am not sure if this can be done - whether via datatable or through any other means. Would be grateful if someone could advise further on this. Thanks, Raj.

Comment: This sounds totally doable, not sure which part you are having difficulties with. The database part depends on what your database supports (for example, SQL query, or REST interface, as long as you get a dataframe or data.table back you can display it. Pagination wouldn't be an issue either if you know how many rows you have.

Comment: Thanks. It is the part where I need to write a custom function that overrides the default filter behaviour of datatable in R Shiny as well as the pagination buttons. There isn't anything available out of the box, but I believe you can do this in the standard js version of datatable.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, sorry I didn't understand what you meant, I thought you were going to create a custom filtering interface using Shiny. If you want to reuse DT's filter/pagination UI, likely you'll need to write custom JS code and call it using DT's `callback` argument.

Comment: Ok, so I came quite far using the example at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html. There is only one outstanding issue in that the filter argument does not seem to be getting passed to the script. For eg., if we add filter="top" in the code, it doesn't work. ```datatable(employee, rownames = FALSE, filter="top", options = list(
  ajax = list(
    serverSide = TRUE, processing = TRUE,
    url = 'http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/scripts/jsonp.php',
    dataType = 'jsonp'
  )
))```